# 404 error while trying to play mp3 file using html5 audio tag on a linux machine when file exists in directory

Tags: linux, html, apache

I have code which needs to load an mp3 file on being clicked and play it. However when I load the page it gives a 404 error like :

```
 "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/main/styles/images/ABCD.mp3"
```

I am using the HTML5 audio tag and as far as the syntax is concerned it is fine as it is a simple code and I'm just trying right now. The file ABCD.mp3 does exist and has permissions as well. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="scripts/jquery.lightbox_me.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/popupCommon.js"></script>


    <title>Popup contact form</title>
 </head>

 <body>


  <!-- Element to pop up -->
    <div class="element_to_pop_up">
        <a class="b-close">x</a>


        <!-- Popup Div Starts Here -->
        <audio controls>
 <source src="styles/images/ABCD.mp3">
 </audio>

        <!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
    </div>

 <div id="my-button" class="boxbare" style="margin:0 2px;padding:2px;cursor:pointer;">
                <div style="min-height:140px;text-align:center;"><img src="styles/images/play.png" /></div>
                <div id="play" class="abut" style="width:120px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;color:black;">play</div>
                </div>

</body>

<!-- Body Ends Here -->

</html>
```

Please neglect the position of the file. I have kept it in the image folder just for trials and to ensure that I am placing the file in the right directory.
The list result on the terminal is as follows;

```
[root@localhost /]# cd /var/www/html/main/styles/images/
[root@localhost images]# ls -al ABCD.mp3 

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 35971 Jan  9 13:48 ABCD.mp3

[root@localhost images]#
```

Is there any important thing that I'm missing out here?
How can I use the  tag and access mp3 files?

Comment: Show the verbatim error log entry

Comment: `/main/styles/images/ABCD.mp3` My best guess off the top without seeing anything extra is the path to the file is not correct. Is your home directory for the page set to `html` or `www` ?

Comment: @CayceK , I am pretty confident about the path as I am loading an image from the same directory whicj loads properly

Comment: @covener , As i'm just trying this on a local machine i haven't set a log file but the error on firebug is as mentioned. The only thing I have changed here is the file name. It actually is "high hopes.mp3"

Comment: @covener , could the space between the words be a problem??

Comment: Add `type="audio/mpeg"` to your source call